# Accessing a local variable from a Controller in a Spock test

Tags: grails, groovy

In my Controller, which I'm testing now with a Spock Unit Test, I've in a method a local variable.

During my test, I want to get the value of this local variable.
How is this possible?

Grails 2.2.5

Comment: You can't do that. Also, you shouldn't even consider testing local variables in your unit test, because it doesn't make much sense to test how does local variable change. It matters what your method does when executed - you should expect method returning a result, depending on input you pass to this method. What happens inside the method (e.g. how local variables change their state) - it doesn't matter.

Comment: If it's important, factor it out